# Install TensorFlow 1.15 on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to install tensorflow 1.15 in Windows 10. I tried to use python 3.6.4 and 3.7.8 both with CUDA 10.0 and cuDNN 7.4.

I am using a pip version 21.0.1 although it is from another version of python (maybe it is an issue?)

`pip 21.0.1 from C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`

I tried some commands like:
`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

but I'm not sure what's the link from 1.15 TensorFlow for Windows (preferably with GPU support).

In that case I received a message:
`ERROR: tensorflow-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Would anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Python 3.9

`pip 21.0.1 from C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`. Tensorflow support for Python 3.9 is still ongoing. Please take look at this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44485).

If in case you are using lesser version of Python (3.7, 3.8), make sure path is correct while installing Tensorflow. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that pip is configurated in 3.9 python but I have the 3.7 installed. As I said, I don't know if it is an issue, and if it is, what can I do about it?
The path is corrected in 3.7. I'm using VS Code in Windows and maybe there are some configurations that I do not know how to do change .

Comment: If you don't need two python versions, remove 3.9 version and follow the instructions mentioned [Tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows_1).Thanks!